# finding DNA codon starting with a or t with regular expression

Tags: python-3.x

Given a DNA sequence of codons, I want to get the precentage of codons starting with A or T.

The DNA sequence would be something like: `dna = "atgagtgaaagttaacgt"`. Eeach sequence starting in the 0,3,6 etc. positions <-and that's the source of the problem as far as my intentions goes

What we wrote and works:

```
 import re

 DNA = "atgagtgaaagttaacgt"

 def atPct(dna):
     '''
     gets a dna sequence and returns the %
     of sequences that are starting with a or t
     '''
     numOfCodons = re.findall(r'[a|t|c|g]{3}',dna) # [a|t][a|t|c|g]{2} won't give neceseraly in the pos % 3==0 subseq
     count = 0
     for x in numOfCodons:
         if str(x)[0]== 'a' or str(x)[0]== 't':
            count+=1
            print(str(x))

     return 100*count/len(numOfCodons)

print(atPct(DNA))
```

My goal is to find it without that for loop, somehow I feel there's a way more elegant way to do this just with regular expressions but I might be wrong, if there's a better way i would be glad to learn how! is there a way to cross the location and "`[a|t][a|t|c|g]{2}`" as a regular expression?

p.s question assume it's a valid dna sequence that's why i haven't even checked that

Comment: actually using a loop will be both cleaner and faster in this case

Comment: ty atm i'm interested on learning regular expressions rather than actual\theoretical running times , is there a way to solve it w/o usage of for loop?

Comment: if sequence that you are looking for can only start at every 3rd position, then i don't think that you can do it with just regex

Comment: @Ryba thank you very much btw the sum idea was really more elegant!

Answer (score 1):

A loop will be faster than doing it another way. Still, you can use `sum` and a generator expression ([another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589208/python-list-comprehension-for-addition)) to improve readability:

```
import re

def atPct(dna):
    # Find all sequences
    numSeqs = re.findall('[atgc]{3}', DNA)

    # Count all sequences that start with 'a' or 't'
    atSeqs = sum(1 for seq in numSeqs if re.match('[at]', seq))

    # Return the calculation
    return 100 * len(numSeqs) / atSeqs 

DNA = "atgagtgaaagttaacgt"
print( atPct(DNA) )
```

Comment: tyvm i really liked the sum idea

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to find out the percentage of times `a` or `t` appear in the first of every three characters in the string? Use the step parameter of a slice:

```
def atPct(dna):
    starts = dna[::3]     # Every third character of dna, starting with the first
    return (starts.count('a') + starts.count('t')) / len(starts)
```

Comment: thank you that's indeed an elegant solution:) sadly it's not using regex but indeed i learned a cool way to do it so thanks!

Comment: @LiorA If this is purely a learning exercise, that's great. Just remember that regexes are often overused, and one of the best regex skills to develop is [learning when *not* to use them](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/223640). Using them to split a string on predefined length bounds is almost never going to be a good idea. That said, they're a great tool to have for those situations where nothing else will work. Happy learning.